# What is isInEditMode() and if(isInEditMode()) return;

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

```
  private void init()
    {
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.control_highlight_color));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        setWillNotDraw(true);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        setClickable(true);
    }
```

I ran into the above code while trying to understand how the ripple effect is created.

1) My question is what exactly is `isInEditMode()`. I have taken a look at the developer site and the explanation is a little confusing to me.

2) Another one is the `if(isInEditMode()) return;` code which strikes me as odd. I thought that the if statements check follow the format `if(){return;}.` However, the way that the code above is formatted makes me confuse and I would like to know why it is so.

3) Plus, if the return value is nothing why not just not specifies it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no answers for #2 and #3, there it is:

If you have a single instruction in your `if`, you can omit the curly braces. Plus java doesn't work by indentation but with braces and semi-colons. So you can put the single instruction on the same line as the `if`, it won't make any differences, as long as there is the semi-colon.

For the `return;`, this method returns `void`, so you can't put any object to return. This however allows you to exit the method, i.e. when you have a bad/unexpected value, as `return` immediately ends the method the moment it is called. `return;` means about the same as `return void;` (however I'm don't know if this would compile).

Answer (score 6):

> Explanation is simple  have look at this

**A View is usually in edit mode when displayed within a developer tool(Android studio,Eclipse ...etc). For instance, if this View is being drawn by a visual user interface builder, this method should return true.**

For instance: the class spawns a thread in its constructor, the drawing code relies on device-specific features, etc. This method is usually checked in the drawing code of custom widgets.

so `isInEditMode()` is only for graphical purpose(in Android studio ..etc)

> Another one is the if(isInEditMode()) return; code which strikes me as
>   odd

as its single line code you can omit `{}` brackets .

> Plus, if the return value is nothing why not just not specifies it in
>   the first place?

As method return type is `Void` only return if there.
The reason to put return is java to if view is in edit mode don't want to make operation that are specific to device.

Comment: oh hey I get it thanks for the answer. Do you by any chance can answer #2 and #3 questions?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily see the effect of the line  **if (isInEditMode()) return;**  in preview screen area when writing xml layout in eclipse or android studio. This line would make your custom view is ignored and do not rendered in preview screen. Otherwise, you can see error message below if the render is unsuccessful.

Normally, custom view need to built first since it can be displayed on preview screen. Some can't be rendered and causes error messages at all time. To prevent that annoy while writing xml code, put this line above other init code in your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

isInEditMode() indicates whether this View is currently in edit mode. A View is usually in edit mode when displayed within a developer tool. For instance, if this View is being drawn by a visual user interface builder, this method should return true. Subclasses should check the return value of this method to provide different behaviors if their normal behavior might interfere with the host environment. For instance: the class spawns a thread in its constructor, the drawing code relies on device-specific features, etc. This method is usually checked in the drawing code of custom widgets.